# mpv error - could not get dispmanx

Tags: raspbian, video, raspbian-stretch, ffmpeg

I've tried to install mpv for raspberry pi using [mpv-build](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv-build) (with maal, 256 graphics mem) because I would like to modify the code.

it seemed like it was finally a success until I tried to run something, and I received an error:

```
Playing: Downloads/big_buck_bunny.mp4
 (+) Video --vid=1 (*) (h264 640x360 23.962fps)
 (+) Audio --aid=1 --alang=eng (*) (aac 2ch 22050Hz)
[vo/rpi] Could not get DISPMANX objects.
* failed to add service - already in use?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using *Raspbian* which is a flavour of *Debian*. It has a big repository with precompiled and configured software packets that fits best into the distribution. It is not recommended to compile software by yourself except you want to modify and/or develop it. It is very likely you run into problems like yours. You have to fit the installation from source to the distribution.

But you can find the *mpv video player* in the repository with:

```
rpi ~$ apt show mpv
```

You can simply install it with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt update
rpi ~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
rpi ~$ sudo apt install mpv
```

Before doing this you should clean up your installation from `mpv-build`.

**update:**
OK, you want to modify the code. The best way to do this is to use Debians source packages. This also fit best into the distribution and you can use the build tools from Debian. I used [Raspbian Stretch Lite 2018-06-27](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/). First you have to enable access to the source repositories. On a standard *Raspbian* installation just uncomment the line beginning with `#deb-src` in the *sources.list* so it looks like this:

```
rpi ~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
```

This will use the `stretch` version which is `stable`. You can choose newer sources. If you like then replace `stretch` with `testing` or `unstable` in the *deb-src* line. For this I use default *stretch (stable)*. Update the installation with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt update
rpi ~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
```

If there where some drivers or firmware installed through `full-upgrade` then reboot.

Install the needed build tools with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt install build-essential fakeroot devscripts
```

Make a working directory for building the sources and get the sources from *mpv*:

```
rpi ~$ mkdir -p ~/src/debian/
rpi ~$ cd ~/src/debian/
rpi ~$ apt source mpv
```

Now build the program from source:

```
rpi ~$ cd mpv-0.23.0/
rpi ~$ sudo apt build-dep mpv
rpi ~$ debuild -b -uc -us
```

This finishes without error, only a warning that *lintian* cannot adjust a line of a man page. That is marginal. I get the *Raspbian* packets for installing *mpv* in `~/src/debian/`. Now you can modify the code and do what you want and rebuild with `debuild -b -uc -us`. For further information look at [BuildingTutorial](https://wiki.debian.org/BuildingTutorial).

Comment: definitely useful to know. I would like to modify the code, however

Comment: @Alter Have asked to add this info to your question.

Comment: @Alter I have updated my answer to build *mpv* from Debian sources.

Comment: Do you if this comes with MAAL hardware acceleration?

Comment: @Alter I'm unsure if I understand your question but I don't know nothing about development of *mpv*. Now you can look into the sources if it uses acceleration.