# How to enable mod_sftp on proftpd?

Tags: raspbian-stretch

I read mod_sftpd is not compiled by default. So, I tried to manually install proftpd-basic downloading it from [here](http://http.debian.net/debian/pool/main/p/proftpd-dfsg/proftpd-dfsg_1.3.5b.orig.tar.gz), following the steps described [here](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_sftp.html#Installation) but something went wrong.
When I run `sudo make` I have this error:

```
msg.c: In function ‘sftp_msg_write_mpint’:

msg.c:449:12: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘BIGNUM {aka const struct bignum_st}’

   if (mpint->neg) {

            ^~
Makefile:34: recipe for target 'msg.lo' failed

make[2]: *** [msg.lo] Error 1

make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/proftpd-dfsg-1.3.5b/contrib/mod_sftp'

Makefile:41: recipe for target 'shared' failed

make[1]: *** [shared] Error 2

make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/proftpd-dfsg-1.3.5b/modules'

Makefile:39: recipe for target 'modules' failed

make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

I tried to search for similar questions but I did not find anything related to raspberry

Comment: Did you try the version available from Raspbian?  Does it not work?

Comment: You should use the source packages from debian. These respect the build environment and will not produce errors about missing components.

Comment: @joan in raspbian packages I founded only deb packages without the possibility of re-compile it. If I install it with 'apt install' mod_sftp is not installed

Comment: @ingo as I wrote, I tried with debian proftpd source code, but when I run "sudo make" appears the error above

Comment: Have a look in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.  The repositories will probably start with `deb`.  Duplicate those lines but replace `deb` with `deb-src` in the copies.  That will make the source packages available.  Remember that Debian uses particular versions because they have been tested to be compatible with the rest of the packages/libraries.

Comment: @joan I downloaded proftpd source and I have these packages:
- proftpd-dfsg_1.3.5b-4.debian.tar.xz
- proftpd-dfsg_1.3.5b.orig.tar.gz
- proftpd-dfsg-1.3.5b
- proftpd-dfsg_1.3.5b-4.dsc
I tried again to recompile proftpd (from proftpd-dfsg-1.3.5b dir) with `./configure --enable-openssl --with-modules=mod_sftp` but I obtain the same error

Answer (score 1):

You say you downloaded *proftpd source* and it seems you download it from the link *here*. But this is the wrong source for the source. As suggested in the comments you should use the sources from the debian repository because they have been tested to compile with *debian*. To install a source from the repository you use

```
rpi ~$ apt source proftpd-basic
```

But before doing it there is a little bit more to do. You can look at [mpv error - could not get dispmanx](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/85799/79866) for an example to install *mpv* from source but the procedure is exactly the same.

Comment: In my last comment I use exaclty the command `sudo apt source proftpd-basic` (with this [output](https://pastebin.com/fZFwcKqV) ).
Before to run configure command, have I run `rpi ~$ sudo apt build-dep mpv` and `rpi ~$ debuild -b -uc -us` as mentioned in your link?

Comment: @bit You should do the same steps but replace the word **mpv** with the word **proftpd-basic**.